# how to use a nav-tag-based nav-bar with seperators that are not part of the link

Tags: css, tags, nav, separator

I am interested in using the nav tag instead of *div>ul>li>a* for a horizontal nav menu.

I am able to get the nav bar and insert separator characters.

With the *div>ul>li>a* approach the added separators are not part of the link since they are added on the li.

when I use *nav>a* and insert separators they are included as part of the link.

I tried:  **nav a:before:link{text-decoration: none;}**  in the css but this did not work.

Also the addition of **text-decoration:none** in the css that adds my separators did not work.

> nav a:before {content: "|"; text-decoration: none;}

using *nav>li>a* gives me a vertical list with the default bullets which defeats the purpose of using the nav tag.

here is an example of the output where you can see the "|" separators are included as part of the link.

[image: nav bar with separators included as part of links]

Realized my listed efforts above (which did not work) would only have removed the underline (not the link) even if they had worked.  I would like to remove the link from the separators but might settle from removing the underline if that is all I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both of these worked: html (just put the separator directly in the nav)

```
<nav>
  |<a href="s">dsa</a>|
  <a href="a">sdf</a>|
  <a href="d">rsd</a>|
</nav>
```

or put the separator in a p-tag that the a-tag is nested in:

CSS:

```
nav p{display: inline; margin-right:15px;}
nav a{margin: 10px}
```

with html:

```
<nav>
   <p><a href="t">fdd</a></p>
   <p>|<a href="e">fdd</a></p>
   <p>|<a href="d">fss</a></p>
   <p>|<a href="d">gde</a></p>
</nav>
```